# Write program which finds shortest expression for number

Tags: math, fastest-code

Write program which finds shortest expression for big integer.
Expression may consist of `+ - * / ^ ! ( )` operations.
`!` stands for factorial, `^` - exponentiation, `/` - rational division.

Number itself should be printed when no shorter expression found.
Examples:

```
7 - 7
120 - 5!
19683 - 3^9
191102976 - 4!^6
```

Code which is able to find shortest expression within 10 minutes or faster for each unsigned 64-bit number.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've searched but didn't find that question. I can delete my question.

Comment: Wait for a few other opinions. Yours allows a fixed set of operators instead of saying "optimise for a language of your choice". That's why I didn't close vote right away. (I actually tried finding it via the search as well, but failed, so I had to browse through my own answers.)

Comment: I think this is sufficiently different from the other question. I don't know what the close votes are for, but I do think the input range needs to be specified (otherwise it could be any number up to infinity.). Also, be aware that fastest-code means the submissions must be tested on the same machine (your machine) so it's a lot of work for you. Code-golf is an easier choice for the poster.